# Making Bootstrap modal resizable with jQuery UI issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

So I have a Bootstrap modal I've created and I am trying to make it resizable using jquery. I have the resize working horizontally but if you try to resize vertically its like the content inside of the modal is not contained within the element I am trying to resize.

I tried using the 'alsoResize' property on the `.resizable()` and included all the divs within the modal but that seems to cause other issues.

```
$('.modal-content').resizable({
    alsoResize: ".modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer"
});
```

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/p7o2mkg4/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You actually did everything right! But the default `overflow` behaviour of HTML elements is `visible`. So if the parent element's content gets overflowed, they break out of the modal and that doesn't look good! So, you need to set the CSS `overflow` property to `scroll` or `hidden` to fix breaking on small size. Try adding:

```
.modal-content.ui-resizable {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

This will ensure scrolling on overflow of the element.

**Link to JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/p7o2mkg4/1/

Comment: Thanks! In my case I didn't want the scrollbars to show up if they weren't needed so I made a small update to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mb0hngdz/) for that.

Answer (score 2):

This works (css)

```
#myModal>div{
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles across this like I have, make sure you have both jQueryUI.js and jQueryUI.css.

I thought having only jQueryUI.js was enough, but it turns out adding the stylesheet is why it wasn't working for me.